# Где можно найти, какие разрешения имеют различные тачфоны?

Tags: веб-программирование, android, оптимизация, iphone

Здравствуйте. 
Кто знает, где можно найти, какие разрешения имеют различные тачфоны (`Android`)? 
И еще. Такой парадокс: 
У `iPhone 4`, разрешение, 640х960. Но для веб, максимальная ширина элемента туда помещается 320px.  
У ZTE Blade (`Andriod`), разрешение 480x800, но для веб, также максимальная ширина элемента туда помещается 320px. 
С чем это связано и как в таком случае ориентироваться, какую ширину элементов ставить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно создать базу девайсов, где по юзер-агенту определять различные параметры данного девайса. Погуглите на тему wurfl.

> > максимальная ширина элемента туда помещается 320px.

Про какую такую максимальную ширину идёт речь ? Куда помещается ? Если вы говорите про веб (html странички) - то какую вы ширину зададите - такая и будет.

несколько не понятно о чем речь, поэтому вопрос выглядит несколько сумбурным.

Comment: При загрузке страницы, масштаб браузера, на сколько я знаю, установлен на 100%. Ну так вот, если установить ширину, допустим, картинки 320px, то она как раз станет на всю ширину экрана. Я про это говорил. Т.е., если другими словами, максимальная ширина элемента, которая не будет выходить за границы видимости.